# Replicate .NET Entity Framework ConnectionString usage logic for Azure Storage

Tags: .net, entity-framework, connection-string, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Please consider the following scenario:

```
Executable -> BLL -> DAL -> SQL DB
```

With Entity Framework you may declare the connection string in the app.config of the `Executable` and let the `DbContext` descendant class in `DAL` make use of it in order to access the db, something like so:

Connection string in `Executable` app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDBContext" connectionString="xxxx" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And the DbContext in the `DAL`

```
Partial Public Class EFDBContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=EFDBContext")
    End Sub
End Class
```

or in C# if you may:

```
public partial class EFDBContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDBContext() : base("name=EFDBContext") { }
}
```

Now, I'm writing a DAL  to access Azure Table Storage Services (may it be Queues or Tables) and as of now I'm passing the connection string from the `Executable` to the ctor of the `DAL` (through the `BLL`).

But I started to wonder: is there a way to do it like for DbContext in EF? Or, is there a way to robustly replicate it? I would prefer it to some extent.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could leverage `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to retrieve your connectionstring or appsetting as follows:

```
string connString=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<your-appsetting-key>"].ToString();
OR
string connString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<your-connectionstring-name>"].ConnectionString;
```

Then, you could construct your `CloudStorageAccount` as follows:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
```

For an ideal approach, I recommend that you could use `Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager` to retrieve your appsetting:

```
string connString=CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("<your-appsetting-key>");
```

Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it.

**DAL**

```
public class AzureTableStorageUserDAL
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("<your-appsetting-key>"));
    CloudTableClient _tableClient;
    CloudTable _table;

    public AzureTableStorageUserDAL()
    {
        _tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        _table = _tableClient.GetTableReference("Users");
        _table.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public UserEntity AddUser(UserEntity user)
    {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(user);
        var result=_table.Execute(insertOperation);
        return (UserEntity)result.Result;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class UserEntity : TableEntity
{
    public UserEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public UserEntity() { }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, that was my original solution, but it bothered me with the thing I had to use (and reference) `CloudConfigurationManager` in my `DAL`, so I ended up just passing the full connection string to the ctor. Hence, I would rather keep CloudConfiguration access out of my `DAL` and go with `Executable` app.config, if even possible.

Comment: Both `CloudConfiguration` and `ConfigurationManager` could read appsetting/connectionstring from your executable app.config. In my opinion, if you do not want to reference `CloudConfigurationManager` and `ConfigurationManager`, then you need to build your method to retrieve the settings from the executable app.config by yourself.

Comment: I was already testing that, because, YES, I totally forgot that referenced libraries can read executables connectionStrings via `ConfigurationManager`. Thank you